# git push -u master branch should have been git push -u origin branch

Tags: git

While I was pushing to my feature branch for the first time, I mistakenly pushed my commits by entering:

`git push -u master feature_branch`

However, to keep it consistent with other's on my team, I should have entered:

`git push -u origin feature_branch`

Is there any way I can change it so that it's in origin instead of master?

Comment: No renaming the remote will not affect anybody else: it is a local command. And I suggesting you check your remote first.

Answer (score 1):

Examine the output of `git remote -v`.

[Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58667021/git-push-u-master-branch-should-have-been-git-push-u-origin-branch#comment103643733_58667161) on another answer suggests that you may have mistakenly renamed your origin remote. Rename it back with with

```
git remote rename master origin
```

As an alternative, you may want to discard your `master` remote with

```
git remote remove master
```

Although merely convention, the name `master` has strong association with the name of a *branch* and will be the source of severe confusion as the name of a remote.

Comment: Great! I will try that. If I rename the remote, will that affect anyone else's branches or just mine? Same question with deleting. Sorry, I'm relatively new at git and still getting used to relationships within branches.

Answer (score 0):

`git push -u master feature_branch` should not have worked, and trigger the error message

```
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

If you type `git remote -v`, you should see only `origin`.
If not:

```
git remote rename master origin
git remote set-url origin https://the/right/url
```

[`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) uses as argument `<repository> [<refspec>…​]`

`master` is not a repository.

So you should not have anything to fix here.

Comment: The push did go through, however. When I check the branch names in my IDE, it shows up as master/feature_branch. My commits also show up in the remote repo when I select the branch.

Comment: Then you need to check the output of Git remote -v.